# Lua & OO, how to access method from another method?

Tags: oop, lua

So if I have an Object and needs to call one method from another within that Object, how do I construct that call?

```
TestObject = {}
TestObject.__index = TestObject

function TestObject.new()   
    local self = setmetatable({}, TestObject)
    self.value = init
    -- a count [integer] of something. Not important what
    self.counter = 99
    return self
end

function TestObject:getCount()  
    return self.counter
end

function TestObject:getCountPlus(add_value)
    -- HERE HOW SHOULD THIS BE FORMATED??
    return self.getCount() + add_value
end
```

And using this Object would be something like this:

```
local testObject = TestObject.new() 
testObject:getCountPlus(1)
```

which should result in 100.

Comment: `self.getCount()`->`self:getCount()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getCount()` needs to know what instance it is in. When you write

```
function TestObject:getCount()
```

it is same as writing

```
function TestObject.getCount(self)
```

(note the colon changed to dot). So calling `self.getCount()` is like calling `getCount` with `self=nil`. Do `self:getCount()`, which is same as `self.getCount(self)`. This may seem odd: why does interpreter not provide self automatically? It's just the way the language was designed: it only provides self automatically with the `:` notation.